# Media and all images disappeared from my wordpress site

Tags: media

I only added a plugin call WPFreshstart 5 to my site and later when I went into my site I noticed all media library was gone and all images thru out my site were gone even the widget area.  I deleted the plugin but nothing has come back.  I've done nothing else to my site except that plugin.  What has happened ?  What can I do to restore my media library?  Could it be a hosting issue?

Comment: Do you have a backup of the site? It could be that this plugin just deleted all of the data - there is no getting it back without a backup. If you don't have one, ask your hosting provider, they usually restore theirs for a small fee

Answer (score 0):

Go into your document root, then locate your media folder (default `wp-include/media`) and raw files (jpgs etc) should be there. If not, check your trash bin, if not, your hosting provider is your last resort.

Edit: after this, download all your files as backup into your local machine, including media and settings etc and reinstall WordPress.

Comment: In wp-include? I doubt it. Uploaded files go under wp-content/uploads normally, and I'd expect any extra files under wp-include to be lost when updating WordPress.